# could two 10Mbit/s links work on the same UTP cable?

Tags: networking, camera

I need to connect two POE cameras (POE mode A) to a POE switch (POE mode A).
But there is only one CAT6 cable that I can use (30 meters span), and I don't want to slip on another one, because there is no room for it in the same conduict (it took me 8 hours to make the first cable fit and I'm sure I will not be able to install the second one). I don't want to place another switch close to the cameras either.

As the camera uses only 4 wires of the UTP cable (100Base-TX, POE mode A), I wonder if the spare wires could be used for the second camera. I would crimp both the cable ends with 2 RJ45 connectors. Two RJ45 of one end will be plugged in two switch's ports, the other two RJ45 to the two cameras.
I don't mind to reduce the speed to 10Mbit/s if necessary, as the cameras' throughput is only 4Mbit/s.

I know it is completely out of standard, but that doesn't mean it will not work.

Before testing it I'd like to ask: 
Did someone already did a similar test? what was the result?

Comment: Can't you just put a switch at the camera end?

Comment: No, they won't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you propose should work fine with 10 megabit or 100 megabit ethernet and POE mode A.

It won't work for gigabit ethernet or POE mode B.

Comment: Can't say about POE, but I have done this successfully for normal 100M network and two machines in a place where only one cable could go, so can also say it should work.